# I cant view a BufferedImage image on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage

I am having a problem with the code below. If I load the image directly into the JPanel I can see it. But when I try to draw it first to the BufferedImage before drawing the BufferedImage on the JPanel the image is not visible. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Duafeb
 */
public class RTester {
    BufferedImage backBuffer;
    Graphics2D g2;
    Pane pain;
    Image img;




    public RTester(){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Sprite Tester");
        frame.setSize(1200, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        backBuffer= new BufferedImage(1200,700,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g2=backBuffer.createGraphics();
        pain=new Pane();
        frame.add(pain);
        Toolkit tk=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        img=tk.getImage(this.getClass().getResource("running.png"));


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
      public class Pane extends JPanel{
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g3=(Graphics2D)g;
            g3.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);

        }
    }     

      public void display(){
          g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
          g2.fillRect(0, 0, pain.getWidth(), pain.getHeight());
          g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, pain);
          pain.repaint();
      }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        RTester test=new RTester();
        test.display();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Reimeus I didn't mean for you to delete your answer, my comments were simply observations, after some testing, I think you were on the right track...

Comment: @Reimeus I believe your answer was heading the right direction.  If you restore it, I'd be happy to up-vote it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that don't feel right about this...

The first is, you create a `Graphics` context to `BufferedImage`, but never `dispose` of it.  Be careful, on some systems this can prevent the contents from been rendered, but this might relate to the screen device rather than a `BufferedImage`

For example, if I alter you code to paint the contents directly within the `paintComponent` method instead of to the `BufferedImage`, the image will be displayed (all bit a split second after the window becomes visible).

I'm not sure what it is you're trying to achieve by using the `BufferedImage`, but you could achieve the same thing straight through the `paintComponent` method

Instead of using `Toolkit.getImage`, you could use `ImageIO.read`, which guarantees that when it returns, the image is fully loaded (or will throw an `IOException` if it fails) or as @Reimeus had previously suggested, using a `MediaTracker` to ensure that the image is properly loaded before you continue using it.

So, you have four options....

### One

Use a `MediaTracker` to wait for the image to be loaded...

```
MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(frame);
mt.addImage(img, 1);
try {
    mt.waitForAll();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

### Two

Use `ImageIO.read` instead...

```
img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("running.png"));
```

### Three

Render output directly in the `paintComponent` method...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g3.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g3.fillRect(0, 0, pain.getWidth(), pain.getHeight());
    g3.drawImage(img, 0, 0, obsever);
}
```

### Four

Use you own `ImageObserver` to ensure that when the image is updated, you re-render it to the backing buffer...

```
private MyImageObsever obsever;

public void display() {
    if (obsever == null) {
        obsever = new MyImageObsever(this);
    }
    g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, pain.getWidth(), pain.getHeight());
    g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, obsever);
    pain.repaint();
}

public class MyImageObsever implements ImageObserver {

    private RTester tester;

    public MyImageObsever(RTester tester) {
        this.tester = tester;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        tester.display();
        return (infoflags & (ALLBITS|ABORT)) == 0;
    }

}
```